# ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1 ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small ORA-06512: at line 22

Tags: oracle, plsql

While doing an import in an oracle 10G database using imp, I receive following error:

```
IMP-00017: following statement failed with ORACLE error 604:
 CREATE TABLE DASHBOARD_ADMINISTRATOR
 (ID NUMBER(19, 0) NOT NULL ENABLE,
 USER_NAME VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL ENABLE,
 NAME VARCHAR2(50), FIRST_NAME VARCHAR2(50));

IMP-00003: ORACLE error 604 encountered
ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small
ORA-06512: at line 22
```

When doing the same thing in TOAD, I have the same error even if I only try to create the table with only 1 column specificied, which is even more strange since I only have 2 lines...

Creating a table called DASHBOARD_ADMINISTRATO is possible, DASHBOARD_ADMINISTRATORR gives again the same error.

However, when I switch places of the words in the name, it works fine.

There is no limit set on tablename length because several of the imported tables have more characters.

I used the same dumpfile to import into oracle 11G and there it was successful.

Any ideas, someone?

Thx for your help.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please [edit] your question and clean up the syntax (get rid of the `"`, and wrap the lines in a sane way so we can execute it without having to manually remove the linebreaks et.c). Also explain what exactly you mean by "However, when I turn the 2 wors around, it works fine". Finally, try to narrow it down to a [MCVE] (e.g. get rid of the STORAGE clauses).

Comment: One more note: Why on earth do you still use `IMP` ? Is this a legacy import? `IMPDP` has been the designated successor of `IMP` for ages.

Comment: I know but export was done using exp by habit. We will start using expdp/impdp asap. But the problem is not because I used imp, I have the same problem while creating the table manually in TOAD.

Answer (score 0):

"character string buffer too small" - Mayby try to increase Varchar Tables. And change number(19,0) to number(19) - ID's is just an integer, they don't have coma, period. In importing/exporting various scenarios came out :)